# Keras training accuracy got result less than 60 percent

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need help on how do I increase the accuracy of my training using keras with tensorflow as backend.

First I downloaded the public electrical dataset from here --> http://plaidplug.com/

Then I picked 5 dataset for each category, selecting 2000 row of Current(I) each dataset, stacked them and save it as `input.h5`

The file will have structure like this. I named this stacked matrix as `currentdata`

```
[[~2000 of data for AC],
 [~2000 of data for AC],
 ...,
 ...,
 ...,
 [~2000 of data for CFL],
 [~2000 of data for CFL],
 ...,
 ...,
 ...,
 [~2000 of data for Fridge],
 ...,
 ...,
 ...,
 ...,
 ...,
 [~2000 of data for Heater]]
```

Then I created a `txt` file for the output. The file consists of the following string indicating the number of dataset(5) for each category:

```
AC,AC,AC,AC,AC,CFL,CFL,CFL,CFL,CFL,Fridge,Fridge,...,Heater,Heater,Heater,Heater,Heater
```

Below is my code

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import pandas
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

seed = 7 
np.random.seed(seed)

### load dataset with 2000 row ###
input_data = h5py.File('input.h5', 'r')
output_type = open('output.txt', 'r')

X = input_data['currentdata'][:] ## input the stacked matrix
Y = output_type.read().split(',') ## read output 

## encode class value as integer
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
## convert integers to dummy variables (one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

weight_path = "/home/fang/workspace/myproject/weight/"

def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(800, input_dim=2000, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(400, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(200, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(11, activation='softmax')) ## 11 output category based from PLAID dataset

    ## Compile model
    #opt = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.02, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    ## save the architecture
    model_json = model.to_json()
    with open('current_data_11type.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json)

    ## save the weight
    model.save_weights(weight_path + 'current_data_4type.h5')

    return model

#estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=500,batch_size=64, verbose=0)
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardized', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=400, batch_size=32, verbose=0)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

#results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
print ("Accuracy: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" %(results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

I tried with and without `StandardScaler()` but that did not give any good result either. The highest accuracy that I got is 57%.

I also experimented with `SGD` optimizers with learning rate `0.01~0.06` instead using `adam` but that also did not give me a good result.

Adding layers, changing the `batch_size` from as lower as 5 to 10 and to use 32, 64, 128 also did not do me any good.

My system :

```
OS:Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
processor:Intel® Core™ i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4
RAM:4GB
GPU:GeForce 920MX 2GB
```

I also tried to increase my data size.(> 5000 row) But that will give me `ResourceExhaustedError`

Does anyone have any idea or suggestion on how do I solve this kind of problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you clarify: what are the targets? You explained the data, but I am not sure which part of the data should be the targets.

Comment: hi, I don't understand what you mean by target but all I can say is that with this amount of data (like in the question), I want to get an accuracy as high as 90% and above. And I want to get the machine to learn that for example this specific 2000 data is for 'AC', and the other specific 2000 data is for 'fridge'. I hope this is what you're asking for.

Comment: In the context of supervised classification, targets mean the true labels of your data.

Comment: from what I understand, the target must be the 2000 data right? forgive me if it is wrong as there are still more about keras and machine learning that I need to learn.

Comment: The target is what you want to predict and what the network is supposed to learn to predict.

Comment: apparently there is pattern for each category. for example, 2000 Current(I) data of AC showing a specific pattern, same as the other category. They have their own specific pattern. I am thinking to get the machine to learn these pattern so in the future I can use the model, input some random Current(I) dataset and it can predict which category the dataset belongs to